# pgr_createTopology does not create vertices at every end of the lines of a street network

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, geometric-network

I am using pgRouting with a street network. I added lines to the network that represent straight lines from destination points I am interested to the nearest street using `ST_ShortestLine()`. Now I ran `pgr_nodeNetwork()` to split the street network accordingly, so that it is ready for basic routing. However, when I run `pgr_createTopology()` the vertices are not all included to have efficient routing:

```
select pgr_createTopology('my_table_wgs84', 0.0001, 'geom', 'street_id');
```

Here is a screenshot, which shows that for the highlighted red line, there are actually no vertices (red rectangles) created at all (plus you see that the connection line I created from the green destination point is actually splitted into several sublines by `pgr_nodeNetwork`):

[image]

For the red line, for instance, the source and target is both the red rectangle you see in the bottom left.
What might be the issue that `pgr_createTopology` don't create vertices everywhere a line ends?

Comment: If you think this is a bug, would you be able to prepare a reproducable example and file an issue on the pgRouting Github account? We can then take a look if it's a data problem or a mistake in the query or a bug: https://github.com/pgrouting/pgrouting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tolerance 0.000001 instead of 0.0001.